# Class Cast exception: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl

Tags: java, jboss, classcastexception

I'm struck with a problem in jboss. When I try to deploy my .war into the server, I get this following error,

`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserF
actoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory`

from which, it is quite evident that there is a clash of libraries. So, I removed the jar file which contains xerces, which happened to by jaxp-ri-1.4.1.jar. Now, when I try to re-deploy, I get this new error,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.getXMLReader(Digester.java:944)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1765)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initServlet(ActionServlet.java
```

where it is complaining that it can't find the xml parsers.

So, now my questions is that does anybody know what can be a solution. Any jaxp jar file that doesn't contain the xerces package?

**Update**

I did as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278213/jboss-class-cast-exception-com-sun-org-apache-xerces-internal-jaxp-documentbui/4278355#4278355) and now I have a new error,

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl
```

which is a class from one of the jars I deleted which contains SaxParserFactory :(

Comment: Hi, I did as you suggested and now I have a new error,

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl

which is a class from one of the jars I deleted which contains SaxParserFactory :(

Comment: Any information that we could have on the newly deleted JAR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you've deleted the wrong JAR. The original ClassCastException was reported when an instance of SAXParserFactoryImpl (which is a subtype of SAXParserFactory) is being cast to SAXParserFactory.

The exception is more likely to be due to the fact that there are two instances of SAXParserFactory rather than two instances of SAXParserFactoryImpl being loaded in the JVM. At the time of casting, the SAXParserFactory loaded by a different classloader was returned resulting in the exception. The fix therefore is to identify JARs in your classpath that have conflicting versions of SAXParserFactory. Removing the parser implementation itself might not be wise, if Commons Digester is looking for a particular implementation.

Comment: The jar I previously deleted was jaxp-ri-1.4.1.jar which gave me the NullPointerException. Now I deleted the jaxp-api.jar. I used jarfinder.com to find in which all jars SaxParserFactory is present and out of all jars I have the jaxp-api.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to verify how you've inherited these JARs in your project. You don't need a copy of either jaxp-ri-1.4.1.jar or jaxp-api.jar to parse XML, especially when you're using the Sun JDK. The JDK/JRE itself has the necessary APIs and the parser implementation that could be used. At best, you'll need the Xerces library (with only the required JARs), as some of the JARs in the distribution cause this issue (xml-apis.jar in particular from Xerces 2.x).

Comment: We use maven for our project. So, it should have included. Surprisingly there is no mention of these jars in pom.xml too. Our project is a webservices project, so I thought we might need them for marshaling. I'll try and see what happens when I delete jaxp-* files.                                                                Thanks for the tips all the way...

Comment: Ah, then you might want to check which dependencies are pulled in by Maven due to the webservice libraries included. I'm not sure if you can mark the appropriate dependencies as runtime dependencies that would be provided by the container, in the POM. If all else fails, consider segregating your webservices from the Struts actions, possibly into a separate web module.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing... You're using JBoss 5.1. If so then it's xml parser and classloading issue. You must define jboss-classloading.xml

See http://www.coderanch.com/t/523519/JBoss/Cast and http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-application-ser...oss-5-classloading-issues.html

Comment: Yes, it is must probably a class loader issue.

Comment: One more thing: using jboss-classloading.xml is simple and lets us solve our problems very fast, but sometimes it's necessary to analyze our application more carefully. We should make sure it's not a matter of libs/class copnflict. It's not easy, but if we don't, we may fall in trouble. Classloading issues cause veeeery strange errors. Eg. in my case I was able to deploy my app as exploded war, but not as archived war. What turned out to be a solution? Removing jboss-classloading.xml and some libs :)