# JSP does not compile in CQ5?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, aem

I am currently working on Adobe CQ 5.5, few days back I tried connecting to and External Database i.e. Oracle.

I succedded in that but later on I suddenly started getting weird errors.

**When ever I create new component i.e. JSP , the JSP doesn't get compiled and Classfile is not created under /var/classes/org/apache/jsp/apps**

**WHY ?????**
When I was trying to connect to Database I added dependent OSGi Jars in Felix console, can these jars be reponsible for the Error ??? Just guessing.. I tried removing the jars still JSP doesn't compile .
sometimes it say Class cast sometimes something else ....

**Edited::
First It said taglib not found,and now it says something else
this is another trace. sometimes it works,sometimes it doesn't what do I do ?? CQ is behaving weird**

```
Error during include of component '/apps/xxx/components/loginpage'

Error Message:

org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException: org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
Processing Info:

Page    =   /content/mywebsite/Login    
Resource Path   =   /content/mywebsite/Login/jcr:content    
Cell    =   loginpage   
Cell Search Path    =   loginpage|page  
Component Path  =   /apps/xxx/components/loginpage  
Sling Request Progress:

      0 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) TIMER_START{Request Processing}
      0 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) COMMENT timer_end format is {<elapsed msec>,<timer name>} <optional message>
      0 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) LOG Method=GET, PathInfo=/content/mywebsite/Login.html
      0 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) TIMER_START{ResourceResolution}
      0 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) TIMER_END{0,ResourceResolution} URI=/content/mywebsite/Login.html resolves to Resource=JcrNodeResource, type=cq:Page, superType=null, path=/content/mywebsite/Login
      0 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) LOG Resource Path Info: SlingRequestPathInfo: path='/content/mywebsite/Login', selectorString='null', extension='html', suffix='null'
      0 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) TIMER_START{ServletResolution}
      0 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) TIMER_START{resolveServlet(JcrNodeResource, type=cq:Page, superType=null, path=/content/mywebsite/Login)}
      0 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) TIMER_END{0,resolveServlet(JcrNodeResource, type=cq:Page, superType=null, path=/content/mywebsite/Login)} Using servlet /libs/foundation/components/primary/cq/Page/Page.jsp
      0 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) TIMER_END{0,ServletResolution} URI=/content/mywebsite/Login.html handled by Servlet=/libs/foundation/components/primary/cq/Page/Page.jsp
      0 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) LOG Applying Requestfilters
      0 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.bgservlets.impl.BackgroundServletStarterFilter
      0 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter
      0 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter
      0 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter
      0 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.theme.impl.ThemeResolverFilter
      0 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet
      0 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter
      0 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter
      0 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) LOG RedirectFilter did not redirect (MobileUtil.isMobileResource() returns false)
      0 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter
      0 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) LOG Applying Componentfilters
      0 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter
      0 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter
      0 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) TIMER_START{/libs/foundation/components/primary/cq/Page/Page.jsp#0}
      1 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) LOG Including resource JcrNodeResource, type=xxx/components/loginpage, superType=null, path=/content/mywebsite/Login/jcr:content (SlingRequestPathInfo: path='/content/mywebsite/Login/jcr:content', selectorString='null', extension='html', suffix='null')
      1 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) TIMER_START{resolveServlet(JcrNodeResource, type=xxx/components/loginpage, superType=null, path=/content/mywebsite/Login/jcr:content)}
      1 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) TIMER_END{0,resolveServlet(JcrNodeResource, type=xxx/components/loginpage, superType=null, path=/content/mywebsite/Login/jcr:content)} Using servlet /apps/xxx/components/loginpage/loginpage.jsp
      1 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) LOG Applying Includefilters
      1 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter
      1 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter
      1 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) TIMER_START{/apps/xxx/components/loginpage/loginpage.jsp#1}
     77 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) LOG SCRIPT ERROR: org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
     77 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) TIMER_END{76,/apps/xxx/components/loginpage/loginpage.jsp#1}
     78 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) LOG Found processor for post processing ProcessorConfiguration: {contentTypes=[text/html],order=-1, active=true, valid=true, processErrorResponse=true, pipeline=(generator=Config(type=htmlparser, config={}), transformers=(Config(type=linkchecker, config={}), Config(type=mobile, config=org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.JcrPropertyMap@ae983e), Config(type=mobiledebug, config=org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.JcrPropertyMap@8d2f9f), Config(type=contentsync, config=org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.JcrPropertyMap@1317315), serializer=Config(type=htmlwriter, config={}))}
     79 (2014-04-29 10:36:22) TIMER_END{79,Request Processing} Dumping SlingRequestProgressTracker Entries
Full Exception:

org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException: org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:385)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:170)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:456)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:500)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:45)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilterWithErrorHandling(WCMDebugFilter.java:183)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:150)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:219)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:257)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.dispatchRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:297)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.dispatch(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:216)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.include(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:103)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter$ForwardRequestDispatcher.include(WCMComponentFilter.java:381)
    at org.apache.jsp.libs.foundation.components.primary.cq.Page.Page_jsp._jspService(Page_jsp.java:106)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:420)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspServletWrapperAdapter.service(JspServletWrapperAdapter.java:59)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:233)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:453)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:358)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:170)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:456)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:500)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:45)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:147)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.filterRootInclude(WCMComponentFilter.java:308)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:141)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:257)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.RequestSlingFilterChain.render(RequestSlingFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter.doFilter(TimeWarpFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:296)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.doFilter(RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet.doFilter(FormsHandlingServlet.java:220)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.theme.impl.ThemeResolverFilter.doFilter(ThemeResolverFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter.doFilter(WCMRequestFilter.java:89)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter.doFilter(RewriterFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.bgservlets.impl.BackgroundServletStarterFilter.doFilter(BackgroundServletStarterFilter.java:135)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:206)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:96)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:42)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:179)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:238)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:48)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:39)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletRuntimeEnvironment.service(ServletRuntimeEnvironment.java:250)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.RequestDispatcherImpl.doFilter(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:315)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.RequestDispatcherImpl.service(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:334)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.RequestDispatcherImpl.service(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:377)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletHandlerImpl.process(ServletHandlerImpl.java:351)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.HttpListener$Worker.run(HttpListener.java:625)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.sling.api.SlingException: org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspExceptionInternal(JspServletWrapper.java:582)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:499)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:399)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspServletWrapperAdapter.service(JspServletWrapperAdapter.java:59)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:233)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:453)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:358)
    ... 93 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlBaseTLV.validate(JstlBaseTLV.java:152)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlFmtTLV.validate(JstlFmtTLV.java:96)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.validate(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:761)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateXmlView(Validator.java:1774)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Validator.validate(Validator.java:1743)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:179)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:311)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:291)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:278)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:599)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:355)
    ... 98 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Team Lead solved it, **THIS is a BUG in CQ 5.5.**
Sometimes when everything is right and you haven't done anything wrong the problem could be with CQ.

Solution
Steps:

1. Shut Down CQ
2. **Delete the launchpad folder**
3. Restart CQ

Tada it works !!

Answer (score 3):

Your error mentions that it can't resolve the Sling tag library. Are you including a reference to it in your JSP (either directly or via the global.jsp script that references it?). I.e. within your JSP:

`<%@taglib prefix="sling" uri="http://sling.apache.org/taglibs/sling/1.0" %>`

or

`<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp" %>`

Comment: Well Ofcourse I am including global.jsp, CQ is behaving weired sometimes it compiles sometimes it doesn't. It was working before and now again it has stopped working. Please help me what should I do ....??

Comment: There's no point in saying "of course" in fairness, if you haven't given any code for the JSP itself. The stack trace you've listed now looks like it's related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278213/class-cast-exception-com-sun-org-apache-xerces-internal-jaxp-documentbuilderfac