# CQ5 JSP throws error at global.jsp include, why?

Tags: java, apache, jsp, aem, ojdbc

**The absolute uri: http://sling.apache.org/taglibs/sling/1.0 cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application**

This is the error I have been getting since I uploaded an OSGi converted version of OJDBC6 Driver Jar as I am building a CQ application that interacts with external database. 
Even after I delete the jar, I still get that error. Not a single JSP is compiling.

Sometimes I get another error called Class Cast Execption, orag.apache.xercers somthing  SAXParserFactoryImpl  cannot be cast to SAXParserFactory.

I deleted the launchpad folder refering to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23338390/jsp-does-not-compile-in-cq5) and started CQ again. It worked for sometime but then again the JSP's stopped compiling.

Please help me everytime a different Exception is popping up.
I am using CQ5.5

I have also read [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-361) and [this](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/sling-scripting-jsp-taglib.html) please see. does this mean I have to make change in the Global.jsp, as I am getting the error at include of global.jsp ?

Thanks in advance.

**Update - Adding the stacktrace**

```
18.09.2014 14:26:54.444 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1411030614328] GET /content/geometrixx/en/products/triangle/overview.html HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Uncaught SlingException org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://www.day.com/taglibs/cq/1.0 cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:51)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:409)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTLDLocation(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:315)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:148)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:415)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:467)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1417)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:133)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:216)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:103)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:168)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:311)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:291)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:278)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:599)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:355)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspServletWrapperAdapter.service(JspServletWrapperAdapter.java:59)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:233)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:453)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:358)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:170)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:456)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:500)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:45)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilterWithErrorHandling(WCMDebugFilter.java:183)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:150)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:219)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:257)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.dispatchRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:297)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.dispatch(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:216)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.include(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:103)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter$ForwardRequestDispatcher.include(WCMComponentFilter.java:381)
    at org.apache.jsp.libs.foundation.components.primary.cq.Page.Page_jsp._jspService(Page_jsp.java:106)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:420)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspServletWrapperAdapter.service(JspServletWrapperAdapter.java:59)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:233)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:453)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:358)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:170)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:456)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:500)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:45)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:147)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.filterRootInclude(WCMComponentFilter.java:308)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:141)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:257)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.RequestSlingFilterChain.render(RequestSlingFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter.doFilter(TimeWarpFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:296)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.doFilter(RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet.doFilter(FormsHandlingServlet.java:220)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.theme.impl.ThemeResolverFilter.doFilter(ThemeResolverFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.zensar.utils.impl.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:40)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter.doFilter(WCMRequestFilter.java:89)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter.doFilter(RewriterFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.bgservlets.impl.BackgroundServletStarterFilter.doFilter(BackgroundServletStarterFilter.java:135)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:206)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:96)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:42)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:238)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:179)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:48)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:39)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletRuntimeEnvironment.service(ServletRuntimeEnvironment.java:250)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.RequestDispatcherImpl.doFilter(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:315)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.RequestDispatcherImpl.service(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:334)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.RequestDispatcherImpl.service(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:377)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletHandlerImpl.process(ServletHandlerImpl.java:351)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.HttpListener$Worker.run(HttpListener.java:625)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
18.09.2014 14:26:54.543 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1411030614529] GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Resource /favicon.ico not found
18.09.2014 14:26:54.573 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1411030614529] GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1] org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.AbstractBundlePersistenceManager cachename=versionBundleCache[ConcurrentCache@1e10d51], elements=1267, usedmemorykb=1065, maxmemorykb=8192, access=26543, miss=1267
18.09.2014 14:26:54.605 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1411030614529] GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1] org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.AbstractBundlePersistenceManager cachename=crx.defaultBundleCache[ConcurrentCache@17efacc], elements=2632, usedmemorykb=8124, maxmemorykb=8192, access=1846072, miss=326148
18.09.2014 14:26:54.655 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1411030614529] GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.servlets.resolver.internal.SlingServletResolver Calling the error handler resulted in an error org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException: org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JasperException: /apps/sling/servlet/errorhandler/404.jsp(73,2) The absolute uri: http://sling.apache.org/taglibs/sling/1.0 cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:385)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:170)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:456)
    at org.apache.sling.servlets.resolver.internal.SlingServletResolver.handleError(SlingServletResolver.java:764)
    at org.apache.sling.servlets.resolver.internal.SlingServletResolver.handleError(SlingServletResolver.java:477)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl$1.render(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:320)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
    at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter.doFilter(RewriterFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.handleError(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:327)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:167)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:206)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:96)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:42)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:238)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:179)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:48)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:39)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletRuntimeEnvironment.service(ServletRuntimeEnvironment.java:250)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.RequestDispatcherImpl.doFilter(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:315)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.RequestDispatcherImpl.service(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:334)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.RequestDispatcherImpl.service(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:377)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletHandlerImpl.process(ServletHandlerImpl.java:351)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.HttpListener$Worker.run(HttpListener.java:625)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JasperException: /apps/sling/servlet/errorhandler/404.jsp(73,2) The absolute uri: http://sling.apache.org/taglibs/sling/1.0 cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:88)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Parser.processIncludeDirective(Parser.java:334)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseIncludeDirective(Parser.java:367)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:459)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1417)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:133)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:216)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:103)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:168)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:311)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:291)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:278)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:599)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:355)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspServletWrapperAdapter.service(JspServletWrapperAdapter.java:59)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:233)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache
```

.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:453)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:358)
    ... 47 more
18.09.2014 14:26:54.656 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1411030614529] GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.servlets.resolver.internal.SlingServletResolver Original error null

**Update 2-** I am aware that sometimes some bundles have dependencies. So I added those too in OSGi Console.

**But now not a single CQ5 page opens up(Not even WCM page) it says 404 error DefaultGetServlet I tried to remove all my jars from OSGi Console but then even that console doesn't respond now. And this has happened in my QA environment so I have no access to launchpad folder nor can I restart CQ**

I will ask the QA  Server handlers to restart the CQ instance.

**But can you tell me what caused my entire CQ5 to breakdown like this ?**

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is often a symptom of the fact that some of your OSGi bundles have not activated; this is a common problem.  Take a look at the Bundles tab on the [Apache Felix Web Console](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-web-console.html) and check that all your bundles show Active rather than Installed. You can click the arrow icon (in the Actions column) to activate a bundle that's only Installed--sometimes this does the trick.

If a bundle refuses to start (activate), there might be several reasons.  You can click the disclosure icon (next to the bundle name) to drill into the bundle to get more information.  This might provide a clue.

Incorrect OSGi bundle dependencies are sometimes the culprit.  I would be curious about that OJDBC6 driver that you have added.  You might explore rolling back your installed code to a point before you added the driver.

Comment: I agree this is the most common problem. Maybe the driver hides another library or there is a version conflict of a referenced library which prevents a mandatory bundle to start.

Comment: @David : Please see the update 2  That I have added!!